# Configure mod_wsgi WSGIScriptAlias with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-12.04, mod-wsgi

I want to redirect ex.com to www.ex.com but I still want www.ex.com/ to point to my app.wsgi without it showing up in the url.

When I use the conf below and I go to ex.com, I get a 404 error saying can't find www.ex.com/app.wsgi/

If I change the WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/ex/app.wsgi to 
WSGIScriptAlias /app.wsgi /var/www/vhosts/ex/app.wsgi

Then all my url look like www.ex.com/app.wsgi/blabla/...

Is it possible to use some kind of rule to redirect ex.com to www.ex.com and still keeping / as the app.wsgi root?

my conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.ex.com
ServerAlias ex.com *.ex.com

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

WSGIDaemonProcess ex user=www-data group=www-data processes=1 threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/ex/app.wsgi


<Directory /var/www/vhosts/ex>
    WSGIProcessGroup ex
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, if using WSGIScriptAlias, your WSGI script file should not be under DocumentRoot for the site.

Anyway try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

You are the one adding the slash in the rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have ServerName and ServerAlias reversed. You don't need the RewriteRule.

Comment: I don't think this is the case.  Elaborate?